# Bank of America on iPhone

Tags: ios, banking, onlinebanking

I have made an app and need to implement Bank of America account usage in it.

I have heard that Bank Of America provide API for iPhone........

Where to get it and how to use it?

Please help....

Comment: Yes this is correct, no one bank can give the own API for development.If it will happen then its will very dangerous for bank security.

Comment: U will develop this application if and only if bank should have give you permission about that.

Comment: thanks all..........for your comments.........

Comment: Hi, friend please check out following link it may be helpful for u,http://www.jongsma.org/gc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using www.buxfer.com. they have an easy API for downloading transactions. they aggregate data from very many banks including Bank of America (bofa). bofa works, sort of. i've been playing with it and i've seen transactions missing from the downloads (they do show up in their webapp though) and an inability to figure out if a transfer is IN or OUT of the account.

other than that (and no reply from buxfer), it is very, very slick.

Answer (score 0):

APIs for Bank of America may indeed exists, but are private to the Bank of America. There is no public API for accessing their services directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API's for Bank of America